# WCF WSDL get rid of qXX namespaces

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, .net-4.5

I have WSDL exported from WCF service with singleWSDL parameter applied.

There are a lot of qXX XML namespaces used like in the following fragments for type and method.

```
<xs:complexType name="PrincipalReference">
  <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
    <xs:extension base="q2:EntityReferenceBase">
      <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="GetPermissions">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="principal" nillable="true" type="q1:PrincipalReference"/>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

PrincipalReference class is inherited from EntityReferenceBase. Both PrincipalReference and EntityReferenceBase are in the same C# namespace and have one and the same value of Namespace field of DataContractAttribute. So they are in one namespace by all means.

Can I somehow get rid of these q1 and q2 XML namespaces? Web-service is intended to be used from various environments (platforms/languages), so clearer WSDL is, happier I am.

I can, for instance, just as a workaround, stop using inheritance, copy base class content to derived ones and thus solve q2 problem, but I have no idea what to do with q1 namespace applied to method parameter type.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do the following:-

Use the namespace attribute when annotating your service contracts and data contracts. Something like this for example:-

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://some.url/2012/11")]

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://some.url/2012/11")]
```

Also, when you are setting up your endpoint, ensure you set the `bindingNameSpace` attribute:-

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="someBindingConfiguration" 
          bindingNamespace="http://some.url/2012/11"
          contract="Some.Contract" />
```

Comment: I did this already. Namespace field is set on every attribute. All namespace values are the same.

Comment: Sorry @adontz I hadn't read your post properly so answered the wrong question. I don't see an obvious way of getting rid of q2:EntityReferenceBase on the xs:extension. As you've said, you could refactor PrincipalReference so that it doesn't inherit from a base class. The other thing you could try (I don't know if this would work) would be to make EntityReferenceBase an abstract class - this *may* have an effect on the generated xsd.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the strange thing was it first had not have these q1, q2, q3 prefixes. 
I am using the DataContract serializer and I missed to cover all I needed with DataContract and DataMember attributs. After that these prefixes were gone.

Also take care about what you serialize, I had a TimeSpan value that I had to replace to an int, so that this did not happen anymore.